# How to dynamically set position of widget in RelaltiveLayout?

Tags: android, dynamic, runtime, android-relativelayout

I am using `RelativeLayout` with `Imageview` and few buttons.

I am dynamically changing the size of the ImageView according to the size of the screen (using`Display` class). The problem is that one of the button's location refers to the `Imageview`.

How do I dynamically change its location according to the new size of the `Imageview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#requestLayout%28%29) when you updated the imageView.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I found my problem (I allow myself to be an idiot few times a week - this one is the first time....)